# how to migrate multiple taxonomy terms with entity lookup plugin

Tags: migrations

Im using the code below to migrate a taxonomy term with multiple values and I get this error below.  is there a way to migrate multiple taxonomy terms with this plugin? :

> InvalidArgumentException: Placeholders must have a trailing [] if they
> are to be expanded with an array of values. in              [error]
> /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php:744

```
field_states_operating_in:
    - plugin: entity_lookup
      source: field_states_operating_in
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      value_key: name
      bundle_key: vid
      bundle: states_operating
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field that you're migrating has multiple values and you're trying to run entity_lookup as though it has only one. I think you just need to make sure you're iterating over the values with the sub_process plugin.

Using [this issue post](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus/issues/2995152#comment-12788050) as a reference, along with the docs for [entity_lookup](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_plus/blob/HEAD/src/Plugin/migrate/process/EntityLookup.php):

```
field_farbzuordnung:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_farbe
    process:
        target_id:
        plugin: entity_generate
        source: value
        value_key: name
        bundle_key: vid
        bundle: alle_farben
        entity_type: taxonomy_term
        ignore_case: true
```

...I think you'd want to do something like

```
field_states_operating_in:
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      source: field_states_operating_in
      process:
        target_id:
          plugin: entity_lookup
          source: target_id
          entity_type: taxonomy_term
          bundle: states_operating
          bundle_key: vid
          value_key: target_id
```

I'm not entirely sure that the source and value_key are correct but I think this should get you most of the way there.